# How to find all images on a webpage, including those defined in background?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, how to identify all images?

A straightforward approach is to traverse all DOM elements, and check: 1) if it is an `<img />`; 2) if its style includes `background-image`.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: here is similar problem may give you a cloue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837714/how-to-get-the-element-background-image-in-html-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

To get all img elements

```
var allImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

To check if any element has a background-image, I might try something like this:

```
if (element.style['background-image'] != null) {/* your code */}
```

I'm not entirely sure about the 2nd one.

Comment: second one won't if you don't define inline style

Comment: @Daiwei is correct. If the `background` is assigned in CSS instead of inline style, `ele.style.backgroundImage` get nothing. See my comments to @ghostrider.

Comment: @Daiwei & lichgo: yup, you're right. I've been working with cases where I manipulate styles when they were written inline, lately. It shouldn't work if it's not written inline, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Get all images on the page:

```
function img_tag_find()
{
    var img_collect = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); //collection of image
    var img_collect_massiv = []; //array for image 
    for (var i = 0; i < img_collect.length; i++)
    {
        img_collect_massiv.push(img_collect[i].src); // push next image
    }

    return img_collect_massiv; // return array of image
}
```

Get element with style = 'background-image' - can be offered as Ramdas Nair

```
if (element.style['background-image'] != null) {/* your code */}
```

or try so (through all the elements, but not sure what's right do not have time to check)

```
function find_backgroundImage()
{   
    var object = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var img_collect_massiv = []; //array for element page 
    for (var childItem in object.childNodes)
        if (object.childNodes[childItem].style['background-image'] != null)
            img_collect_massiv.push(object.childNodes[childItem]);

    return img_collect_massiv; // return all element with style = 'background-image'    
}
```

Comment: If the `background-image` is assigned in CSS instead of inline style, `ele.style.backgroundImage` gets nothing. So in addition to check the `style` property, use `ele.currentStyle['background-image']` for IE and `var v = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ele, ''); v.getPropertyValue('background-image');` for W3C standard to detect if background has been defined in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

For cases when background image is defined in CCS, check whether an HTML element has a background image or not this way:

```
window.getComputedStyle(htmlElement).backgroundImage
```

The best way to gather all background images on a page would be to walk through all of active CSS to gather all of `background-image` references along with the style tag/class names to which the corresponding background images apply. Then only select HTML elements that match the corresponding styles all while making sure that they are not collapsed/hidden/display-none'd.